# Ignore Null values from the database ConsoleTvs Charts

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, charts, highcharts

So I have a set of data that needs to be displayed on the admin dashboard.
I decided to use laravel charting package ConsoleTvs Charts by Erik Campobadal.

I am using the package above to create charts directly from the database, the issue is, within my table (user's table for example) there are columns with NULL value.

How do I ignore this null values and represent only columns with real values on my chart?

```
`
 $chart_print_media = Charts::database(User::all(), 'pie', 'highcharts')
                ->title('Print Media Campaign')
                ->dimensions(450, 300)
                ->groupBy('print_media',null);`
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Eric Campobadal, am just going to post the answer here for anyone that this might help in the future.

`

```
$users_print = User::all()->filter(function ($user) {
                return $user->print_media !== null;
            });


            $chart_print_media = Charts::database($users_print, 'pie', 'highcharts')
                ->title('Print Media Campaign')
                ->dimensions(450, 300)
                ->groupBy('print_media');
```

`

I believe this is self-explanatory enough